# Process & Threads states after termination / blocked

Tags: multithreading, process

Say I have a running process with 2 running threads, what happen to the threads if the process is terminated? do they get terminated as well?

Also, what happen to the threads if the process is 'losing' the CPU attention (Other process took the CPU's attention) and therefore the process is in waiting state / suspended. Do its threads keep running? or?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the threads get disposed of by the operating system if and when the process terminates and gets cleaned up.

The threads in a process are scheduled according to their priority. In most OSes that is fairly straight forward, it's a simple matter of the higher priority threads winning. Windows does something different, a process's priority is adjusted by Windows according to whether it is the foreground process. Thus the process's threads' priorities are also adjusted...

Comment: Ok.. but what happens if there were running threads and the process which they are within got suspended? Do they stop running?

Comment: Ok, so a process is a container for one or more threads. Anything that affects the process as a whole affects the thread(s) within the process. Remember that the code running from main() is also a thread, just not one that you've explicitly started.